# Nested if statement not working correctly

Tags: delphi

So I am making a project that allows a user to change their password in a database, one of the latter stages of the code which is that they must re-enter the correct password again in order for it to change is not working here it is:

```
if tblusers.locate('StudentID', sStudentID,[]) then
begin
  if soldpass = tblusers['Password'] then
  else
  begin
    showmessage('Incorrect Current Password');
    exit;
  end;
  tblusers.edit;
  tblusers['Password'] := snewpass;
  if snewpass <> sreenter then
  begin
    showmessage('Re-Enter your Password correctly');
    edtreenter.clear;
    exit;
  end
  else
    tblusers.post;
  showmessage('Password Successfully Changed');
end;
```

The problem is that last if statement is not working properly because they can re enter a totaly different password and it will still change it

Comment: Learn to properly indent your code, so that you can more easily follow the flow of execution. Recent versions of the IDE will format the code for you so that you get an example of how that indentation should look. Writing sloppily indented code is difficult to read and understand. Also, using the debugger to step through the code can help you solve logic errors. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is an excellent time to start learning.

Comment: Also, code like `if soldpass = tblusers['Password'] then else` is very poor. Instead, you can just use `if soldpass <> tblUsers[;Password'] then begin`, which is much cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm still a student so learning is always part of the process, I  will look into the debugger then maybe I'll be able to solve my issue

Comment: Whilst indentation is entirely optional in Delphi/Pascal (and most C family languages) and is irrelevant to the compiler, it is easier on you, and anyone reading your code to treat it like Python, where indentation is part of the syntax. Code tends to be read many times, but only written once.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use small and capital letters. your text message is difficult to understand, don't use same words for different messages type.

```
var
  ...
  s_Msg : string;
begin
  if sOldPass <> tblUsers['Password'] then
    s_Msg := 'wrong password' // 'login failed', 'incorrect password' ...
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('login successful'); // 'password is correct', 'login done' ...
    tblUsers.edit;

    if sNewPass <> sReenter then
    begin
      edtreEnter.clear;
      s_Msg := 're-enter password is incorrect'; // 'new password is wrong', 'please confirm your password' ...
    end
    else
    begin
      tblUsers['Password'] := sNewPass;
      tblUsers.post;
      s_Msg := 'password successfully changed';
    end;
  end;
  ShowMessage(s_Msg);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

So I have fixed the issue after consulting with my dad and him helping me better my code
This the the new code which works:

```pascal
begin
  if soldpass = tblusers['Password'] then
  begin
    showmessage('Correct Current Password');
    tblusers.edit;
    if snewpass = sreenter then
    begin
      tblusers['Password'] := snewpass;
      tblusers.post;
      showmessage('Password Successfully Changed');
    end
    else
    begin
      showmessage('Re-Enter your Password correctly');
      edtreenter.clear;
      exit;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    showmessage('Incorrect Current Password');
    exit;
  end;
end
```

Comment: You're still not indenting your code properly. :-) Doing so will greatly improve its readability. I've fixed it here, so you have a better example to work from.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).